# Typescript error TS2345 Error: TS2345:Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am reading some data from RabbitMQ channel and converting it to a JSON object. I'm getting an error in the following line.

```js
let communicationInformation = JSON.parse(newCommunication.content);
```

The error is,

> TS2345:Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Do I need to cast the data? I am using Typescript 2.4.1

```
Amqplib.connect(amqpLibUrl, (err, connection) => {
  if (!err) {
    connection.createChannel((err, channel) => {
      channel.consume('QueueName', newCommunication => {
        if (newCommunication != null) {
          let communicationInformation = JSON.parse(newCommunication.content);
          // Code 
        }
      })
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I think the error is thrown on the input parameter of `JSON.parse`. Try to first call `toString` on it then pass to the function.

```
let communicationInformation = JSON.parse(newCommunication.content.toString());
```

Comment: Don't work in my case "error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'."

Comment: Or use Buffer().toJSON()

Comment: Do not use `Buffer().toJSON()` in situations like this, it looks like an elegant solution but that actually gets you the JSON representation of the buffer and not the bytes in the buffer.  e.g.
`{type:'Buffer', data: [ 123 10, ....]}`

Comment: @Aize You receive 2531 because the default typing for content is datatype | null. One way you can do to fix this is add a ! after content (`newCommunication.content!.toString()`). This tells TS that it cannot be null/undefined and so the error will go away. However, if it can be null, then you can add a ? just after newCommunication (like so: `newCommunication?.content.toString()`). Both will save you a lot of typing, make it look cleaner, and get rid of the error. The other solution is a try/catch.

Answer (score 68):

I am not sure what is newCommunication.content. In my case it is a file and I had to specify encoding for fs.readFileSync:

```js
 const level = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./path/to/file.json', 'utf-8'));
```

Comment: For me the top voted answer and your answer make the error disappear. I have a file content like you.

Answer (score -8):

Next Error was `error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.`

You have to disable strictNullChecks in your compiler

Comment: I'll explain why people are downvoting this instead of downvoting with no explanation

The whole point of typescript is for strict type checks so that you don't make mistakes

Hence, what typescript wants you to do in an error like that is to explicitly check if the object is null, for example:

```if (obj === null) {
//do something
} else {
//Your original code
}```

Comment: Well, it depends, honestly. disabling null checks can be a solution for some cases but most cases, this is not the way.